# Discord bot random reply

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am currently working on a discord bot with a simple mini game. You write "gamestart" and the bot sends you 1 of 4 possible replies. But my bot isn't sending anything. What the problem could be?

```js
bot.on('message', msg) => {
    if(msg.content === "gamestart"){
        var random = Math.random() * (4 - 1) + 1;
        Math.round(random);
        if(random === 1){
            message.channel.send('doggos, axes, chalice');
            
        }
        else
        if(random === 2){
            message.channel.send('sun, axes, doggos');
            
        }
        else
        if(random === 3){
            message.channel.send('axes, sun, chalice');
            
        }
        else
        if(random === 4){
            message.channel.send('chalice, doggos, sun');
            
        }   
    }
    
})
```

Comment: `Math.round(random);` this returns a new value, and doesn't mutate the old. Also note, that your random has a spread of three, while you are trying to differentiate four values. `random === 4` will never happen.

Comment: Maybe try `random = Math.round(random);`

Comment: @ASDFGerte I set the max to 5 so i should work. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: As so often, the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values) is good to read as a start. I missed, that you are using `round` instead of `floor`. This means the second part of my previous comment is slightly wrong. However, it just exchanges one issue for another: while hitting all values, your distribution won't be uniform anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Responses = ["doggos, axes, chalice", "sun, axes, doggos", "axes, sun, chalice", "chalice, doggogs, sun"]; // Storing the responses.
message.channel.send(Responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * Responses.length)]); // Sending a random response.
```

Answer (score 1):

A really simple solution, and -in my opinion- more organized is to create an Array and then have the bot choose one randomly and send:

```
const Answers = ['Answer 1', 'Answer 2', 'Answer 3']; 
msg.channel.send(Answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * Answers.length)])
```

Also (important), change 'message' to 'msg'!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also may be with relevant with message handling and `undefined` channel id.

First of all, make sure that bot is actually listening for a message event, via this code:

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
    console.log(msg)
    if(msg.content === "gamestart"){
        var random = Math.random() * (4 - 1) + 1;
        ...
```

The second this is, all messages (even if they are numbers) are actual strings, make sure that incoming `msg` value is equal with your sentence "gamestart".

As for the third, by default, bot replies to a user in the channel that he have listening, but if you bot listening for a `message` event, but don't have permission to write in current channel to reply, then you are screwed.

Make sure that bot have permission in certain channel, or invite it with `permission=8` (administrator)